# Soft Input Keyboard overlaps with multi - line edit text on android

Tags: android

I m having an issue with multiline edit text inside a scroll view

The issue is that I have added a multiline edit text view inside a  scroll view and this is added dynamically .

I have set the windowSoftInputMode to "adjustPan"

When i select the text area( multiline edit text)  then the softkeyboard overlaps it.

Please see below :-

[image: multiline edit text overlapped by soft key board]

Any ideas how can i change it show the entire multiline edit text 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use adjustresize rather then adjustpan.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: you can't solve this unless you use a scrollview. In adjustresize if your edittext is multiline it automatically scroll up your input and user can see what is he is typing.